# Read a PDF File in ColdFusion

Tags: pdf, coldfusion

**Problem:** Is their a way to determine which PDF file belongs to who? Meaning, lets say I have 30 doctors, and I have 35 PDF files. Let say Doctor A has 5 PDF files belonging to Doctor A. Is their a way to know which 35 PDF files belong to that Doctor?

This is where the read the PDF comes into play. However, I am not sure how to read a PDF file in ColdFusion and determine when the read should end when the Doctor name has been found.

Open to jQuery and JavaScript as well but would like to know in ColdFusion first.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: worth trying this: https://www.raymondcamden.com/2007/07/25/Reading-text-from-a-PDF-in-ColdFusion-8/ Once you can read the content, may be then CF search can be performed.

Comment: https://www.bennadel.com/blog/553-searching-directories-and-file-content-using may be this will help you.